# How to update the values of Magento products using installer/update scripts and Magento abstractions?

Tags: sql, magento, installation, entity-attribute-value

I added a custom eav attribute to my Magento application product entity using an installer script (Basically, following the procedure described here: [Installing Custom Attributes with Your Module](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/installing_custom_attributes_with_your_module)). Now, I want to use an update script to change (populate) the values of this attribute for each product according to some criteria (based on the product category). The script I attempted to use was essentially like this:

```
$attributeValues = array(...) // Map from $productId to the desired  $value
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
foreach($attributeValues as $productId=>$value){
    $product->load($productId)->setMyAttribute($value);
    $product->save();
}
```

My questions would then be: Is it ok to use this level of abstraction (Mage::getModel('catalog/product') and its methods) in update scripts? If it isn't, how would you recommend to change these attribute values using update scripts (without requiring sql)?

The script I used (until now) has not worked and failed with the error:

```
Call to a member function getStoreIds() on a non-object
```

in a magento core file.

I don't know if this error is a Magento bug or is a problem with how I'm using the update scripts.

I'm using Magento 1.4.0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `Mage::app()->setUpdateMode(false)` in your sql upgrade script.  e.g.

```
$installer = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');;
$installer->startSetup();
Mage::app()->setUpdateMode(false);
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore('your_store_code_here');
```

If you look in `Mage::app()->getStore()` you will see the following snippet that returns an incorrect store which is required for saving a product.

```
if (!Mage::isInstalled() || $this->getUpdateMode()) {
        return $this->_getDefaultStore();
    }
```

Comment: Data update scripts are much easier and cleaner. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

### Data update scripts are the way to go

Simply use a data upgrade script for this. This is a script placed in the `data` folder instead of the `sql` folder. Those scripts run later then the database structure updates, and allow access to more functionality.

Example file names:

```
app/code/local/My/Module/data/your_setup/data-install-0.1.0.php
app/code/local/My/Module/data/your_setup/data-upgrade-0.1.0-0.2.0.php
```

This [is already available in Magento 1.4](https://github.com/LokeyCoding/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.4/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php#L179).

Comment: Could you give an example of what else is available to data scripts that aren't available to install scripts?

Comment: Have a look at `\Mage_Core_Model_App::run` which runs `applyAllDataUpdates` just before the controller dispatch. The normal update scripts are run in `\Mage_Core_Model_App::_initModules` after loading the modules but before initializing the DB.